# Why isn't my Readme.md showing up on the Visual Studio Online "Welcome" page?

Tags: markdown, azure-devops

I've created a project in VSO, using a GIT repository, and placed a Readme.md file in the root. Why isn't the Readme.md showing up on the VSO Welcome page?

I'm trying to follow the directions from the following blog posts without luck:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/08/07/project-homepages.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slange/archive/2014/08/20/vso-is-happy-to-see-you-project-welcome-pages.aspx

The GIT repository in VSO has only a single branch, and I can see the Readme.md at the root in the online code explorer. The Readme.md is very simple:

```
# Test Heading
This is just some sample text.
```

I've also tried with a more complex Readme.md. I'm running with just a "basic" VSO license, but as far as I am aware, this is not an advanced feature.

What are other people's experiences in getting this to work?

Comment: From the Team Project's Welcome page are you able to see the git repositories?
Personally, I've had no problems with README files so far.

Answer (score 3):

As best I can tell, this seems to have been a temporary glitch in Visual Studio Online. Without having made any changes, I just re-checked my Welcome page and the Readme.md seems to be appearing now.

However, the feature may still be partially broken, because a secondary markdown file that I placed in the same root directory is *not* appearing.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio view the window 'Solution Explorer' and click the icon 'Show All Files' located in the top of the window. This will make the README.md file visible in the solution. Hopefully it will work the same way on VSO.